# SqlDataSource onSelected event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an SqlDataSource control with a selectcommand that doesn't fire onselected event (while another one, very similar, fires it).
The one that doesn't fire:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="CommunicationSQLDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:aspnet-WebApplication6-20131007103938ConnectionString1 %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM tCommunication" OnSelected="CommunicationSQLDataSource_Selected">
     <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="ProjectID"></asp:Parameter>
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

(The one that fires, just for reference)

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DetailsSQLDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:aspnet-WebApplication6-20131007103938ConnectionString1 %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [ProjectID], ..." OnSelected="DetailsSQLDataSource_Selected">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectID" Type="Object" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

What I see is that the debugger doesn't reach the block of CommunicationSQLDataSource_Selected even though it is referenced in the control.

Comment: The one that fires, the second one, doesn't even have the event hooked up. Are you hooking it up in code?

Comment: Actually it has. Just corrected it here, thanks.

Comment: I read something somewhere that SQL server caching may cause similar problems, but I didn't understand it really and dunno where to set it

Answer (score 0):

be sure you  Use it in Form tag or asp:Content ..upon which Environment used

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DetailsSQLDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:aspnet-WebApplication6-20131007103938ConnectionString1 %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [ProjectID], ..." OnSelected="DetailsSQLDataSource_Selected">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectID" Type="Object" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
  </form>
```

Comment: It says _element 'form' must not be nested within element 'form'_. And please note that the one working isn't in a form element either.

Comment: mmm..ok ..so i think one working in asp.content tag ..can u provide us the complete code please ..

Comment: How do I do that, please? It is too long for a comment.

Comment: anyway, both of them are in the same content tag

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I clicked config. data source, and walked through the wizard without changing anything. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

Set CancelSelectOnNullParameter property to false